# High number of faults, low residual memory and high lock % for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

First off, here is a pastebin with all my [important numbers](http://pastebin.com/d1MPc7UZ) (mongostat, db.stats, db.serverStatus).

The machine it is running on has plenty of memory free:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15965       2277      13688          0         89       1630
-/+ buffers/cache:        557      15407
Swap:         5119          0       5119
```

The database files themselves are on a block device (we previously had issues due to NFS drives) and should be working just fine. To avoid overfilling the logs, I even set --slowms 1000, but still a lot of the queries are slow and it seems like mongodb is just not interested in using more memory to service faster updates.

The use case is that it is 95% updates, with occasionally queries thrown in when we pull out data and compile it. Previously it has worked just fine with this setup, so I am trying to track down any reasons it might not be working.

I am hoping someone more familiar with mongodb can look at the numbers and point me in the right direction.

Comment: One potential cause for low resident memory is a high read-ahead setting on your data drive. Can you check the value? This can be done by running blockdev --getra /dev/XXX where XXX is your device.

Comment: Note that a good initial setting for read-ahead is 32. The default for this is often larger which provides an advantage for sequential i/o. Unless you are running a capped collection in MongoDB you are likely performing mostly random i/o which does not benefit, and you are paying the price in unused data in your file system cache.

Comment: You may want to run iostat -xm 2 as well to confirm disk load.

Comment: You may also want to run `top` to check if CPU is bottleneck, since I don't see really high page faults in your mongostat.
It might be also reasonable to run an .explain() on one of your update statements and post the output here.
Do you have any secondaries in your replica set?
Can you post a db.currentOp() output during the load?

Comment: version 2.0.4 - really?  Why such an old version? it's not even the latest in that branch...

Comment: of the 7 collections, how many are most active?  can you post db.<collection>.stats() for one or two most active ones?  I'm guessing the problem is that you have huge fragmentation problem and that your updates are growing documents and relocating them on disk.  If you add one "sample" line of a slow update from your log file it will confirm or refute the theory.

Comment: I suspect that the "growing documents" theory is correct. We found a bug that was unrelated to mongo but still meant a lot of documents were being grown that should have resulted in newly created seperated documents (through the use of update with upsert: true).